# What does "would" mean in a sentence?

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs, usage

What does "would" actually mean in the following sentence? My friend says that "would" here means "will possible".

> Question: Which is a correct way in a dialogue?
>
> 1a: Have you seen my book?
>
> 2a: Do you see my book?
>
> 3a: Where is my book?
>
> B: The book is on the table
>
> Answer: All three work, but technically speaking, the question B is answering 3. Since 1 and 2 are yes-or-no questions, a more precies answer **would** be "yes, it's on the table". Note that since A already knows he's asking about a book, it **would** be more natural for B to refer to it as "it" than "the book".

Comment: It's a polite way of saying "is" here.

Answer (score 0):

For background, which you likely already know, English has [auxiliary (helper) verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb) and a subset are [modal verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs).  "Will and would" are modal verbs and are used with the verb "to be" to create the [conditional tense](https://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/be.html).

Specifically in this example:

> a more precies answer would be "yes, it's on the table".

Well firstly, precise is spelt wrong.  Secondly, in this context the sentence is saying "a more accurate answer is ...".  The use of the conditional tense implies ambiguity.  And by this I mean it could go either way, the answer is saying "a more accurate answer could possibly, perhaps be ...".  It is basically the author being non-committal.

> it would be more natural for B to refer to it as "it" than "the book".

Again the author is being vague.  I suspect the reason that the author is writing passively (this could be true) instead of assertively (this IS true), is because there is no definitive answer.  It is the case that one might sound more natural, or might be used in preference.  So by changing "is IS the case" to "it would be better" basically fogs the answer and implies that it is perhaps right.

**Additional notes**

To explain this more quantitatively, there is an aspect in English of active/aggressive and passive/polite.  It speaks to the way English people say things that they seemly don't mean, like "that would be an option", actually means "I don't like that option at all".  So to explain the degrees of uncertainty that the conditional tense introduces, let me score the sentences:

- it **is accurate** to say X: 100%, X is definite, no question the way to go.  This is firm and assertive.
- it **is more natural** to say X: 95%, this is a statement, but this is not saying is accurate, there could be alternatives but they are uncommon.  It "sounds better" or is more common to say X
- it **would be better** to say X: 85%, this is comparing something, saying that under certain conditions ([conditional tense](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/)), this probably being one of those conditions, then X is the way to go
- it **would be more natural** to say X: 75%, this is saying that under certain conditions ([conditional tense](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/)), this probably being one of those conditions, then X is the way to go.  But then the "more natural" also introduces some subjectivity, there are other more forced ways of doing it.
- it **could be more natural** to say X: 50%, this is now only a possibility, with alternatives available

Like I said, there are many ways to phrase things, but hopefully this gives an idea of what is meant by "introducing ambiguity" (or indicating the potential for alternatives)

Comment: So, the use of "would" above shows a hypothetical situation or tentative?

Comment: Well, I would say "indicates a slight and possible uncertainty".  I wouldn't say it was straight hypothetical, it just introduces a touch of ambiguity.  This is in contrast to saying "a more precise answer IS...".  If you use "IS", there is no ambiguity, it IS a firm statement.

Comment: Thanks Ariane Kh Anderson. You said "The use of the conditional tense implies ambiguity", what do you mean by that? Does "would" mean "could possibly"? "is" is definite and "would" is not certain because there is other options.

Comment: Let me try to explain it in a more quantitative way, I'll add it to the answer

Comment: Yes, please explain, Ariane Kh Anderson. Because I really want to know its use in this situation.

Comment: Added to answer above under heading "Additional notes".  Let me know if this makes it clearer.

Comment: That's very clear now. Thanks very much for the explanation, Arinane Kh Anderson. One more question, I hear "would" used to be tentative as in "a good time to meet **would** be after lunch", "any help **would** be appreciated." my question is: what is the meaning of "tetative"?

Comment: "a good time to meet would be after lunch" - a proposal at 75% strength!  The person saying this is expressing a preference that is open to negotiation. You could then reply "actually I can only do mornings", which "would" probably be fine.  If this was said without the conditional (imposing, containing, subject to, or depending on a condition or conditions), then it "would" (may) be phrased as "I can only do after lunch".  Even phrases like "it would have to be after lunch" is conditional, it means "IF WE MEET (condition on the if) then it would have to (definite time) be after lunch".

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant explanations, Ariane Kh Anderson. By the way, could you tell me what the meaning of "tentative" is? "would" is often used to be tentative. So what does "tentative" mean?

Comment: A pleasure! The most common use of tentative is to mean _uncertain_, a tentative lunch appointment, a tentative commitment or to say I'll tentatively say yes. It's used to imply uncertain for now but perhaps to be confirmed at a later date.  So "it would have to be after lunch" would be a tentative commitment, pending confirmation from the other party.